# Displaying User Relationships Module Blocks

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I'm unable to display any of the User Relationships' auto-created blocks in any of my sidebars. I have tried enabling all modules and permissions I can think of, with no success. The block I'm most interested in is the block that would allow users to be invited to an existing relationship (e.g. Friend), but as I say this nor any of the other blocks display. Other Drupal blocks and custom blocks display just fine. The blocks do show up in the blocks listing, and I've tried different ways of configuring them. Any help, or even confirmation that someone has been able to do this with the latest stable versions of Drupal and the User Relationships module, would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to trouble you, but I think I found the problem: me! I had the incorrect notion (actually hope) that the "add someone to a relationship" block would display without allowing users access to the overall user list. It turns out that the block does display if a user can select another user from the list of users. I'm sure I'm missing something, but this seems to me like a weakness of the User Relationships module. Would anyone know if the Friendslist module works similarly? Thanks again.